# Error with Reactive Environment for Shiny plot point exclusion

Tags: r, shiny

This is my first question, so please be patient with me. 
I am trying to pass a dataset into an interactive shiny plot. 
Here is the gist of what I have on the server side.

```
sliceData<-reactive({
    sData<-my_data() %>%
      select(one_of(c(input$e1,input$e2,input$e3,input$e4,input$e5)))
    return(sData)
  })

vals <- reactiveValues(
      keeprows = rep(TRUE, nrow(sliceData()))
    )

IA_Plot<-reactive({
  # Plot the kept and excluded points as two separate data sets
  keep    <- sliceData()[ vals$keeprows, , drop = FALSE]
  exclude <- sliceData()[!vals$keeprows, , drop = FALSE]

  IAP<-ggplot(keep, aes(input$e3, input$e4)) + geom_point() +
    geom_smooth(method = lm, fullrange = TRUE, color = "black") +
    geom_point(data = exclude, shape = 21, fill = NA, color = "black", alpha = 0.25) +
    coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1.5, 5.5), ylim = c(5,35))
  IAP
})

# Create single graph plot for interaction ----
output$sPlot <- renderPlot({
  IA_Plot()
})

# Toggle points that are clicked ----
observeEvent(input$sPlot_click, {
  res <- nearPoints(sliceData(), input$sPlot_click, allRows = TRUE)
  vals$keeprows <- xor(vals$keeprows, res$selected_)
})

# Toggle points that are brushed, when button is clicked ----
observeEvent(input$exclude_toggle, {
  res <- brushedPoints(sliceData(), input$sPlot_brush, allRows = TRUE)
  vals$keeprows <- xor(vals$keeprows, res$selected_)
})

# Reset all points ----
observeEvent(input$exclude_reset, {
  vals$keeprows <- rep(TRUE, nrow(sliceData()))
})
```

Here is the error I got from R Studio:

> Warning: Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext: Operation
>   not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do
>   something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or
>   observer.)

Could someone help me with what I am missing?

Thanks!!

Comment: You have `vals` in a ractive context. So,when you call it you still need to use `vals()`

Comment: Hi user5254203: I replaced the vals with vals(), but I am still getting the same error. Thank you for the suggestion though :-)

Comment: you need to provide minimal possible code that can reproduce the error with the data you are working.I cannot reproduce the error with your code here.

Comment: Hi user5249203: thank you for the recommendation. I have reposted the question with minimal possible code to reproduce the error. It is in the following address: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48102599/error-in-reactive-environment-in-shiny-plot